# Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, google-tag-manager

I try the answers in StackOverFlow to fix my problem. But no one works for me.

I run my app and build successful everytime, but sometimes crash to print the crash log and sometimes launch my app successfully.

I don't know why to make two of situation.

`Crash Log:`

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8FB6E110-F30F-425D-9011-A196E78BE7CB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3C10C9A5-9012-4444-B7CF-D0615DED602A/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Reason: image not found
```

This is my `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, and why my `GoogleToolboxForMac.framework` turns light gray color.

I also try `pod install` again, and not work.

How to fix my crash problem?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `rpath` (look in the linker settings) and when deployed is that framework in that folder?

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry, I don't know Where to find `the linker settings`?